# Wildcard in org-agenda-files

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, wildcard

I have a project base folder, `~/prj`, inside of which I have many individual projects, `2014_prj1`, `2014_prj2`, ..., inside of which I have, among others, a `doc` folder.  The layout looks like this:

```
~/prj
~/prj/2014_prj1
~/prj/2014_prj1/README.org
~/prj/2014_prj1/data
~/prj/2014_prj1/doc
~/prj/2014_prj2
~/prj/2014_prj2/README.org
~/prj/2014_prj2/data
~/prj/2014_prj2/doc
```

Now I'd like to add all project directories (`2014_prjX`) to `org-agenda-files`, as well as all `doc` subdirectories of the project directories.  The `data` folders should *not* be part of `org-agenda-files`, because they can possibly contain 10000s of files.

How can I achieve this?  I tried a simple

```
(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("~/doc/notes"
                               "~/.emacs.d"
                               "~/prj/*/doc"
                               )
                        )
```

but this gives me the error

```
Non-existing agenda file ~/prj/*/doc
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the function `file-expand-wildcards` to get all the files matching the wildcard add them to `org-agenda-files` variable. Something like the following

```
(setq org-agenda-files (append '("~/doc/notes" "~/.emacs.d") (file-expand-wildcards "~/prj/*/doc")))
```

Comment: Is there a hook that would allow the set of files to be computed dynamically?  E.g. if I add a new `.org` file after I start emacs, I would still like it to be part of `org-agenda-files`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a more generic approach, which allows you to have deeper nesting. For example, I have a rich tree of notes and some folders have tasks.org file in it. This code will collect all of the fly:

```
(defun set-org-agenda-files ()
  (require 'f)
  (require 's)

  (setq org-agenda-files
    (f-entries org-directory
               (lambda (filename)
                 (s-ends-with-p "/tasks.org" filename))
               t)))
```