# How to add a directory to the org-agenda-files

Tags: org-agenda

Instead of adding `.org` files using `C-c [` I would like to add a directory to my `.emacs` file, as I read it is done [here](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#AgendaSetup).

I only have one directory at the moment, so this is the line I put into my `.emacs`:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("~/Documents/Org")))
```

This path should be pointing to a directory I have, named "Org", where I have a few `.org` files.

However, when I call the Agenda with `C-c a` and subsequently try to gather all `TODO` items with key `t`, I get the following message:

```
Non-existent agenda file ~/Documents/Org. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?
```

I notice that there is a full stop mark in the message, which is not intended. Also, it looks like `emacs` is really asking for a file, not a directory.

Comment: One solution might be to use `file-expand-wildcards` with parameter '~/Documents/Org/*' to get all files in the directory and add them to the org-agenda-files, please take a look at this (http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/wildcard-in-org-agenda-files).

Comment: Thank you, this also works however it is not needed in this instance. I will update my own question as the mistake is much sillier..

Comment: It looks like you figured out the problem.  Could you please change your edit to a full-fledged answer (and accept it once the system allows you)?  It's perfectly acceptable, and fairly common, to do so.

Comment: Oh right! I forgot that `org-agenda-files` can have directories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `emacs` was complaining is because - indeed - there is no file in the specified directory .

Working under Windows, I mistakenly took `~` for my home directory. This is **not** the case.

When meaningful directories are specified as entries in the org-agenda-files variable, `emacs` matches its contents towards the variable `org-agenda-file-regexp` in the `org.el` file, actually allowing for a much finer customization (for instance nested structures).

So the mechanism works just fine.

Source: `org.el` file